# Дописать короткий цикл, который находит индекс значения в списке по части слова

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, циклы, условия

```
item_rating_rp = ['WS98', 'JS99', 'RP100']
for i in item_rating_rp:
    if i.startswith('VIVINO'):
        key = item_rating_rp.index(i)
        item_rating_rp = item_rating_rp[key][2:]
```

Не пойму как сделать, чтобы в случае если слово не было найдено, то в переменную item_rating_rp записывалось значение None, так как индекс в процессе итераций не будет определен.

Comment: Используйте индексы `for i in range(len(item_rating_rp)):
    if item_rating_rp[i].startswith('VIVINO'):` Тогда не нужно будет его повторно искать. Это раз.
Во вторых не очень понятна вот эта запись `item_rating_rp = item_rating_rp[key][2:]` что Вы тут хотите сделать?

Comment: @Namerek 
`item_rating_rp = item_rating_rp[key][2:]` в этом случается у меня переменная записывает значение из списка. Допустим, если в startswith я введу "JS", то он мне выведет значение по индексу в списке 99 без "JS".
А если совпадения не будет, то по сути и индекса нет,  то мне переменную item_rating_rp надо записать значением None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Если я правильно Вас понял, то Вы имели ввиду что-то вот такое:

```py
item_rating_rp = ['WS98', 'JS99', 'RP100']
prefix = 'JS'

for i in range(len(item_rating_rp)):
    item_rating_rp[i] = (
        item_rating_rp[i].removeprefix(prefix)
        if item_rating_rp[i].startswith(prefix)
        else None
    )

print(item_rating_rp)
```

---

```
[None, '99', None]
```

### UPD

```py
item_rating_rp = ['WS98', 'JS99', 'RP100']
prefix = 'JS'
for item in item_rating_rp:

    if item.startswith(prefix):
        item_rating_rp = item.removeprefix(prefix)
        break
else:
    item_rating_rp = None

print(item_rating_rp)
```

---

```
99
```

Comment: Нет, не совсем то. На выходе мне нужно, чтобы было одно значение  в переменной. Нужно, чтобы переменная переписывалась на тот же самый допустим 99, а если JS нет в списке, то переменной будет присваиваться None

Comment: @niksmns, Проверьте. Так? Правда не очень понял зачем переопределять переменную, вместо того, чтобы создать новую.